# Combining two distributions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 2x1800 dimensional data. Both features I approximated separately with the following distributions:

[image]
[image]

How to combine these two distributions to plot them as a multivariate distrubution's surface graph?

Comment: Knowing the marginals isn't enough to determine the joint distribution. Are you assuming the two random variables are independent?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming they are independent. I was trying to estimate multivariate distribution directly, but the it works bad. So I was thinking I can somehow check if first with combining 1-D estimations (which worked good for me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For independent random variables the joint distribution is the product of the marginal distributions. Use `meshgrid` to generate the appropriate indicies. Here we assume the marginal distributions are stored in arrays `px` and `py`

```
[xidx,yidx] = meshgrid(1:numel(px),1:numel(py));
pxy = px(xidx).*py(yidx);
surf(xidx,yidx,pxy);
shading('interp');
```